# Ruby Format Validations [ No Whitespace ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, models

I'm trying to create a format validation for a text field that will reject anything with whitespace.  Can someone help me out with the RegEx syntax?  This is what I've tried:

```
no_whitespace = /\A[\S]\z/i

validates :customurl,  :format => { :with => no_whitespace }
```

I'm new to programming and clueless about RegEx.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
no_whitespace = /^[\S]+$/
```

That should specify no whitespace characters from the beginning (^) the the end ($) of the string, and at least 1 character.

Comment: AWESOME!  I think that did it!

Comment: You should use `/\A\S+\Z/` just in case some malicious user try to send text with line breaks.  The square brackets aren't necessary.

Comment: `^` is for beginning of a line, not a string. Similarly, `$` is for end of line, not end of a string. That said, the OP's regex should work for the entire string (using `\A` and `\Z`). It's just that the OP forgot to include the `+`. So this would have worked for the OP `/\A[\S]+\Z/`

Comment: @zabba You are perfectly correct, you should use \A and \Z to be on the safe side. However ^ and $ will also work in this case because \S includes lines breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
no_whitespace = /[\S]*/
```

Use [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to help you form and test regular expressions.

Comment: hmm...didn't seem to work.  it still allowed me to pass a value with spaces in it.